# How to use WCF service reference client with X.509 client certificate, which is only available as .pfx file?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security, client-certificates

**Context**

I have a tested working WCF service which is configured to client certificate authentication. Now I would like to call it and provide a client certificate. I would like to use  client class which was generated when I added a service reference to my client project.

NOTE: I *must* load my X 509 client certificate from file or other stream, because the client will run on a PaaS environment, so I will have no access to any OS provided certificate store.

```
X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate(path, password);
```

**Question**

I know I can configure the client in the following way:

```
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
    StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
    StoreName.My,
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
    "myCert");
```

Unfortunately there is no overload for SetCertificate which accepts a loaded X509Certificate instance.

How can I configure my client to use the loaded X509Certificate?

Comment: What about client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate ?

Comment: That was my first shot. but It is read only, that's why the SetCertificate provided

Comment: It is not readonly.

Comment: Many thanks, I mixed it with .ClientCertificate, and not examined the .ClientCertificate.Certificate. Trying. If works that's an answer

Comment: It works. Thanks. In case you post it as answer I am going to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need it just:

```
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate
```